# Build for iPhone without being connected

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am wandering if it is possible to build a developer build in a file which can be downloaded from a/my server by my test users. As it is now I have to connect each device to my computer and build to it?

I have seen when building a phonegap build for iOS in Dreamveawer it generates a file I can install on my iPhone using a QR code?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance!

Comment: just set valid certificates and Control + B. you will find your build under the products folder.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do so but I'd suggest using the free and excellent [TestFlightApp](http://testflightapp.com) to manage distributing your developer builds.

If you do want to distribute an ad-hoc build on your own, then follow these [instructions](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1829415&seqNum=16).

Answer (score 0):

You can archive your app and save it for Ad-Hoc distribution.

Ad-Hoc distribution enables you to distribute your app through an HTML page, it means that clients could install the app using their iOS Safari.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html